# password field eye icon to hide and show password not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, razor

password field eye icon to hide and show password not working

Basically I have a recover password page in that we have two password field and both of them have eye icon to show and hide password its done through java script, its worked perfectly on chrome and edge browser but not working on firefox. Here is the script

```
function togglePasswordVisibility(inputId, iconId) {
     var passwordInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
     var eyeIcon = document.getElementById(iconId);

     if (passwordInput.type === 'password') {
         passwordInput.type = 'text';
         eyeIcon.classList.remove('fa-eye');
         eyeIcon.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
     } else {
         passwordInput.type = 'password';
         eyeIcon.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
         eyeIcon.classList.add('fa-eye');
     }
 }
```

`cshtml:`

```
<div class="form-group mt-4">
    <label class="mb-1"><strong>Password</strong></label>
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control thin-placeholder", @placeholder = "Please enter password", @autofocus = "autofocus", @id = "fakePassword" })

    <i id="toggler" class="far fa-eye toggle-password" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility('fakePassword', 'toggler')"></i>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @maxlength = 50 })
</div>

<div class="form-group mt-4">
    <label class="mb-1"><strong>Confirm Password</strong></label>
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control thin-placeholder", @placeholder = "Please enter confirm password", @id = "confirmfakePassword" })

    <i id="toggler1" class="far fa-eye toggle-password" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility('confirmfakePassword', 'toggler1')"></i>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @maxlength = 50 })
</div>
```

[firefox issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dezAc.png)
[chrome image working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPdLR.png)

Comment: The issue is that the icon doesn't change in FF? Or does FF keep the type of password? Or something else?

Comment: we have two input fields password and confirm password both have an eye icon on pressing eye icon it should change to slashed eye icon and password which is initially hidden need to reveal and viceversa but it doesnt work on firefox its not even clicable ,but in chrome and edge it works fine

Comment: There's seemingly nothing special which wouldn't work in FF. Are you sure the page is not read from the cache when running in FF?

Comment: no i tried hard reset and runned application multiple times its not from cache

Comment: now in edge also its working in some corner of the icon only